# How to replace an element of a nested list by the values of a dictionary, if the key matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list:

```
lst = [[1,0],[20,0],[21,1],[22,3],[24,2]]
```

Also a dict

```
dct = {0:"Balco",1:"Greg",2:"Palm",3:"New"}
```

I want to replace the 2nd element of nested list with the values that match from the dictionary.

So, the expected new list will be:

```
lst = [[1,"Balco"],[20,"Balco"],[21,"Greg"],[22,"New"],[24,"Palm"]]
```

Comment: Can there the values in the list that are not in the dict? In that case, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `for` loop should work:

```py
for item in lst:
    item[1] = dct[item[1]]

print(lst)
```

Or, using list comprehension for a one-liner:

```
result = [[item[0], dct[item[1]]] for item in lst]
```